# Play Games login all times (android/unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have try to add Play Games into my game (on android). I have add my APP in Play Store Dev, and create a game on it.

Now, i use the SDK of google, i have configure it.

The problem is : 
 - When i launch my game, they ask me all time to login. I want save if the user is loggin or not.
 - The leaderboard didn't show when i click on my button, they just ask to login.

For my leaderboard:

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
            Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
});
```

For ADD a score

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class MenuGameOver : MonoBehaviour 
{
        public Text level;
        public Text score;
        public Text bestScore;

        public GameObject newBestScoreLabel;


        void OnEnable(){
                level.text = ScoreManager.GetLastLevel ().ToString ();
                score.text = ScoreManager.GetLastScore ().ToString ();
                bestScore.text = ScoreManager.GetBestScore ().ToString ();

                bool isNewBest = ScoreManager.GetLastScoreIsBest ();

                if (isNewBest) {
                        newBestScoreLabel.SetActive (true);
                } else {
                        newBestScoreLabel.SetActive (false);
                }

            Social.ReportScore(1234, "XX", (bool success) => {

            });


        }
}
```

When i launch my game:

```
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        // enables saving game progress.
        .EnableSavedGames()
        // require access to a player's Google+ social graph to sign in
        .RequireGooglePlus()
        .Build();

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    // recommended for debugging:
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    // Activate the Google Play Games platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Social.localUser.authenticated){
    Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
}else{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
       if(success){
//yay
    }
    });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember `Social.localUser.Authenticate` is to authenticate or login. You are calling it on show leaderboard button. So it will definitely prompt for login. Nothing strange in it. Your line of code is used to check if user is not authenticated before then first login and then show leaderboard.

What you can do is to simply authenticate at launch.

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new       PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
    // enables saving game progress.
    .EnableSavedGames()
    // require access to a player's Google+ social graph to sign in
    .RequireGooglePlus()
    .Build();

PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
// recommended for debugging:
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
// Activate the Google Play Games platform
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
       if (success)
           print("GPGS authenticated successfully");
});
```

And on Leaderboard button you have to call just show leaderboard if user is authenticated otherwise login first then show leaderboard.

```
//On Leaderboard button
if(Social.localUser.authenticated){
    Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
}
else
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
           if (success)
               Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    });
```